# LWJGL3 shared context throws "GLFW_VERSION_UNAVAILABLE"

Tags: multithreading, opengl, lwjgl, glfw

I tried to multi-Thread my application, but when I try to share the context from my main window, the program crashes.

```
[LWJGL]
GLFW_VERSION_UNAVAILABLE
error
Description : WGL: Failed to create OpenGL context
Stacktrace  :   
org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.nglfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1361)   
org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1521)
```

Here is the creation code for the main window:

```
GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();
if (!glfwInit()) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");
}
glfwDefaultWindowHints();
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
if(fullscreen){
    window = glfwCreateWindow(vidmode.width(), vidmode.height(), windowTitle, glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), NULL);
    Var.windowSizeX=vidmode.width();
    Var.windowSizeY=vidmode.height();
}else{
    window = glfwCreateWindow(windowSizeX, windowSizeY, windowTitle, NULL, NULL);
    glfwSetWindowPos(window, (vidmode.width() - windowSizeX) / 2, (vidmode.height() - windowSizeY) / 2);
}

if (window == NULL) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");
}

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
if (vSync) {
    glfwSwapInterval(1);
} else {
    glfwSwapInterval(0);
}
GL.createCapabilities();
```

And the code in my second thread:

```
GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW.GLFW_FALSE);

offsiteWindow = GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(1, 1, "offsite", MemoryUtil.NULL, window);//errors
GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(offsiteWindow);
GL.createCapabilities();
```

What am I doing wrong?
Version: Stable LWJGL 3.1.3 Snapshot build 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one problem here is that you are calling `glfwCreateWindow` from different threads, while

> This function must only be called from the main thread. [[ref](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFW.html#glfwCreateWindow-int-int-java.nio.ByteBuffer-long-long-)]

You have to implement messaging between threads based on `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` or whatever to do only requests for window creation from every thread except the main one while the main thread must listen to these requests and do the actual creation with this function call

Comment: Did that help? I am working on the same thing as you, but I write in Go language. In my code, it was also required to call `GL.init()` to initialize OpenGL explicitly in addition to GLFW initialization. But as far as I can see there is no such need in LWJGL library.

Comment: Still testing, in lwjgl I have to use GL.createCapabilities();

Comment: Not sure what I see but glad that I could help you. However, my code still doesn't work, hehe

Comment: well, the spikes are vertex from the barrels (read back from the vbo, y-position increased by 100 and saved again). Anyway good luck on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If Grief's answer does not work, you also have to ensure that you are calling `glfwCreateWindow` only if the resource share `window` and the windows that already share with this share, must not be current in any thread.

From the `glfwCreateWindow` javadoc:

> Windows: The context to share resources with may not be current on any other thread. [[ref](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFW.html#glfwCreateWindow-int-int-java.nio.ByteBuffer-long-long-)]

You could do this by calling `GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(0)` in the main thread (or the thread where you are creating the main window) and then create the window with the share in the second thread.

Comment: thank you for making that clear. Luckily Griefs answer worked perfectly.